# Change the height of a UITextField in runtime

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextfield, height

I created a UITextField subclass with some subviews and animation - looks like a material design textfield (I want to put it online for everybody to use when I polish it).

The problem I am facing is fairly interesting. When I create a UITextField using Interface Builder, I cannot change the height of this UITextField afterwards. I am using this code and nothing happens:

```
    let theFrame = CGRect(origin: 40, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 40))
    myUITextField.frame = theFrame
```

When I create myUITextField in code (in viewDidLoad method) the above code works. When I create it using interface builder, that code does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: myUITextField.frame = theFrame as cgrect

Comment: if you are using autolayout then you cannot, you need to disable autolayout in your interface builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to edit in runtime the height of a UITextField that you placed using Interface Builder, you should change the "border" property of that textfield to none, using interface builder.

I asked this while creating this subclass: https://github.com/KaanEmec/UIMaterialTextField

Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Autolayout, which may be the reason the height isn't changing at the moment, you can change the height of your `UITextField` by changing the `constant` on the `NSLayoutConstraint` controlling the height. To get that constraint when using IB you can ctrl-drag to from the constraint to your `UIViewController`.